# Access to JSON elements using AJAX function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I need to get data from my codeigniter controller and send it to my view as ajax call. So I use this function to send data to the ajax function

```
function vendorAccess(){
    $result = $this->Admin_model->allvendor();

     foreach($result as $row){
        $data = $row["joinedDate"];

        $now = time(); 
        $your_date = strtotime($data);
        $datediff = $now - $your_date;

        $cont =  round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
         if($cont == 85){
              $response['vendorName'] = $row['vendorName'];
              echo json_encode($response);
        }

     }

}
```

This will send data to my ajax function. My ajax function is this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
     url: '<?php echo base_url();?>/Admin/vendorAccess',
     type: 'get',
     dataType:'text',
     success: function(res){
         console.log(res);

     }
 });    
});
```

Using this code I get the output as this

> {"vendorName":"Cinnamon Grand"}{"vendorName":"Saloon Bhagya"}

Now I need to get the these two vendorName's in to my div using jquery as separate two names. I searched this problem on stackoverflow and I found some solutions. But those solutions do not work for me. One example is bellow

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('#numOfNot').html('New');
    var tmp=null;
     $.ajax({
         url: '<?php echo base_url();?>/Admin/vendorAccess',
         type: 'get',
         dataType:'json',
         success: function(res){
             alert(res.vendorName);

         }
     });    
 });
```

when I use this give me alert with undefined.
Thank you very much for your valuable time to spend to solve my problem

Comment: You can't echo JSON in a loop. Use the loop to create an array of all the results, then convert that to JSON when the loop is done.

Comment: @LGSon `JSON.parse` isn't needed, `dataType: 'json'` does that automatically.

Comment: @Barmar Yes...you are right, missed that _tiny_ part :), deleted

Comment: And in the Javascript, you need to loop over `res`, since it will be an array, not one object.

Comment: @Barmar thank you I understand that I am try to convert that to json when looping then I get the data in two arrays

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Did you do it like in my answer?

Comment: yes I got the answer Thankz again @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a little refactoring to get this to work correctly. The JSON that you're returning is not valid. You'll want to create an array of objects in the `PHP` method and then, outside of your `foreach()` loop, `echo` this data back to the screen using the `json_encode()` method.

**PHP:**

```
function vendorAccess(){
    $result = $this->Admin_model->allvendor();
    $vendors = [];

    foreach($result as $row){
        $data = $row["joinedDate"];  
        $now = time(); 
        $your_date = strtotime($data);
        $datediff = $now - $your_date;

        $cont =  round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

        if($cont == 85){
            $vendors[] = ['vendorName' => $row['vendorName']];
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($vendors);
}
```

Then, in the JavaScript, you'll want to check to ensure you're receiving an array and then loop through the array and use the data at each index in some way. In this instance, I'm logging the data to the *console* with `console.log()` but you could do any additional logic here:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tmp=null;

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>/Admin/vendorAccess',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(res) {
            if(res && res.length) {
                for(var a = 0, len = res.length; a < len; a++) {
                    console.log(res[a].vendorName);
                }
            }
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thank you I got small problem with  $vendors[] = ['vendorName' => $row['vendorName']; How to correct this line. Do I use it like $vendors[] =  $row['vendorName'];

Comment: @D95 Sorry, left off the trailing `]` closing square bracket.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fill in an array in the controller, not echo JSON each time through the loop.

```
function vendorAccess(){
    $result = $this->Admin_model->allvendor();
    $names = array();
    foreach($result as $row){
        $data = $row["joinedDate"];

        $now = time(); 
        $your_date = strtotime($data);
        $datediff = $now - $your_date;

        $cont =  round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
        if($cont == 85){
            $names[] = $row['vendorName'];
        }
    }
    echo json_encode(array('vendorName' => $names));
}
```

Comment: Thank You @Barmar I get the correct way to send data to my ajax function